# jQuery Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Im trying to do a dialog box with jquery. In this dialog box Im going to have terms and conditions. The problem is that the dialog box is only displayed for the FIRST TIME.

This is the code.

JavaScript:

```
function showTOC()
{
    $("#TOC").dialog({ 
        modal: true, 
        overlay: { 
            opacity: 0.7, 
            background: "black" 
        } 
    })
}
```

HTML (a href):

```
<a class="TOClink" href="javascript:showTOC();">View Terms & Conditions</a>

<div id="example" title="Terms & Conditions">1..2..</div>
```

The problem I think is that when you close the dialog box the DIV is destroyed from the html code therfore it can never be displayed again on screen.

Can you please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue with the code you posted. Your function to display the T&C is referencing the wrong div id. You should consider assigning the showTOC function to the onclick attribute once the document is loaded as well:

```
$(document).ready({
    $('a.TOClink').click(function(){
        showTOC();
    });
});

function showTOC() {
    $('#example').dialog({modal:true});
}
```

A more concise example which accomplishes the desired effect using the jQuery UI dialog is:

```
   <div id="terms" style="display:none;">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </div>
   <a id="showTerms" href="#">Show Terms &amp; Conditions</a>      
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#showTerms').click(function(){
               $('#terms').dialog({modal:true});   
           });
       });
   </script>
```

Comment: I agree 100% with you. I think there is different way how to display the TOC in the same page. The problem is that all TOCs are being displayed because they are in a DIV statement. Is there any way how to display the DIV only when someone clicks on the link button?

Comment: See the second example that I just added.

Comment: I tried it (copied&paste ur code but the "LOREM..."is not being displayed in the dialog box and 2. Once the link is clicked the dialog is appeared,then when I click on the close button and then I click again on the the link to see the TOCs again the dialog do not appear... Can you please help me :(?

Comment: Remove the style="display:none;" attribute.

Answer (score 65):

I encountered the same issue (dialog would only open once, after closing, it wouldn't open again), and tried the solutions above which did not fix my problem. I went back to the docs and realized I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how the dialog works.

The $('#myDiv').dialog() command creates/instantiates the dialog, but is not necessarily the proper way to **open** it. The proper way to open it is to instantiate the dialog with dialog(), then use dialog('open') to display it, and dialog('close') to close/hide it. This means you'll probably want to set the autoOpen option to false.

So the process is: instantiate the dialog on document ready, then listen for the click or whatever action you want to show the dialog. Then it will work, time after time!

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready( function(){       
            jQuery("#myButton").click( showDialog );

            //variable to reference window
            $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');

            //instantiate the dialog
            $myWindow.dialog({ height: 350,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                position: 'center',
                autoOpen:false,
                title:'Hello World',
                overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
                });
            }

        );
    //function to show dialog   
    var showDialog = function() {
        //if the contents have been hidden with css, you need this
        $myWindow.show(); 
        //open the dialog
        $myWindow.dialog("open");
        }

    //function to close dialog, probably called by a button in the dialog
    var closeDialog = function() {
        $myWindow.dialog("close");
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>

<input id="myButton" name="myButton" value="Click Me" type="button" />
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none">
    <p>I am a modal dialog</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Helped me out, my problem was that I was instantiating the dialog inside my click() handler, thus it wasn't available to open elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and was looking for a way to solve it which brought me here. After reviewing the suggestion made from RaeLehman it led me to the solution. Here's my implementation.

In my $(document).ready event I initialize my dialog with the autoOpen set to false. I also chose to bind a click event to an element, like a button, which will open my dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Initialize my dialog
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
        "OK":function() { // do something },
        "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
    });

    // Bind to the click event for my button and execute my function
    $("#x-button").click(function(){
        Foo.DoSomething();
    });
});
```

Next, I make sure that the function is defined and that is where I implement the dialog open method.

```
var Foo = {
    DoSomething: function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
}
```

By the way, I tested this in IE7 and Firefox and it works fine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use multiple dialog boxes on one page and open, close and reopen them the following works well:

```
 JS CODE:
    $(".sectionHelp").click(function(){
        $("#dialog_"+$(this).attr('id')).dialog({autoOpen: false});
        $("#dialog_"+$(this).attr('id')).dialog("open");
    });

 HTML: 
    <div class="dialog" id="dialog_help1" title="Dialog Title 1">
        <p>Dialog 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog" id="dialog_help2" title="Dialog Title 2">
        <p>Dialog 2 </p>
    </div>

    <a href="#" id="help1" class="sectionHelp"></a>
    <a href="#" id="help2" class="sectionHelp"></a>

 CSS:
    div.dialog{
      display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $('#dialog1').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'explode'
    });

    $('#Wizard1_txtEmailID').click(function() {
        $('#dialog1').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
    $('#Wizard1_txtEmailID').click(function() {
        $('#dialog2').dialog('close');
        return false;
    });
    //mouseover
    $('#Wizard1_txtPassword').click(function() {
        $('#dialog1').dialog('close');
        return false;
    });

});



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 <div id="dialog1" title="Email ID">
                                                                                                                <p>
                                                                                                                    (Enter your Email ID here.)
                                                                                                                    <br />
                                                                                                                </p>
                                                                                             </div>
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<div id="dialog2" title="Password">
                                                                                                                <p>
                                                                                                                    (Enter your Passowrd here.)
                                                                                                                    <br />
                                                                                                                </p>
                                                                                              </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

RaeLehman's solution works if you only want to generate the dialog's content once (or only modify it using javascript). If you actually want to regenerate the dialog each time (e.g., using a view model class and Razor), then you can close all dialogs with $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(); and leave autoOpen set to its default value of true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more concise and also allows you to have different dialog values etc based on different click events:

```
$('#click_link').live("click",function() {
    $("#popup").dialog({modal:true, width:500, height:800});

    $("#popup").dialog("open");

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution: remove some init options (ex. show), because constructor doesnt yield if something is not working (ex slide effect).
My function without  dynamic html insertion:

```
function ySearch(){ console.log('ysearch');
    $( "#aaa" ).dialog({autoOpen: true,closeOnEscape: true, dialogClass: "ysearch-dialog",modal: false,height: 510, width:860
    });
    $('#aaa').dialog("open");

    console.log($('#aaa').dialog("isOpen"));
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced similar issues. This is how I was able to solve the same

```
    $("#lnkDetails").live('click', function (e) {

        //Create dynamic element after the element that raised the event. In my case a <a id="lnkDetails" href="/Attendance/Details/2012-07-01" />
        $(this).after('<div id=\"dialog-confirm\" />');

        //Optional : Load data from an external URL. The attr('href') is the href of the <a> tag.
        $('#dialog-confirm').load($(this).attr('href'));

        //Copied from jQueryUI site . Do we need this?
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

        //Transform the dynamic DOM element into a dialog
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Details'
        });

        //Prevent Bubbling up to other elements.
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want to change opacity for all dialog then change in jquery-ui.css

```
/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay
{
    background: #5c5c5c url(images/ui-bg_flat_50_5c5c5c_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=80);
}
```