# How to open a jquery dialog box with text from a javascript variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a way to open a jquery dialog box without getting the text from a div, but rather from text in a javascript variable?

Comment: How about setting the text of the div to your var when you open the dialog?

Comment: Looks like this example, only just declare your Javascript variable and insert it into the JQuery method.  Remember, JQuery is Javascript.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366696/jquery-dialog-box

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You could trigger any event and store something to a `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and append a `<div>` element from a javascript variable and then turn it into a dialog using something like this:

```
var dialog =  "<div id=dialog <h1>Some text</h1></div>";
$('body').append(dialog);
$('#dialog').dialog();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Qku/)

```js
var dialog =  "<div id=dialog <h1>Some text</h1></div>";
$('body').append(dialog);
$('#dialog').dialog();
```

```html
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

You can automate this with a function:

```
var createDialog = function(text , title) {
    var dialog =  "<div id=dialog <h1>" + text + "</h1></div>";
    $('body').append(dialog);
    $('#dialog').prop('title' , title);
    $('#dialog').dialog();
}
```

Just call the function passing your variables in as arguments and you get your dialog.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethj/WBXYj/7/)

```js
// initialize title and body variables
var someVariable = "Some text";
var someTitle = "My title";

var createDialog = function(text , title) {
    //create dialog <div> shell
    var dialog =  "<div id=dialog <h1>" + text + "</h1></div>";
    
    // create the dialog <div>
    $('body').append(dialog);
    
    // update the <div>'s title
    $('#dialog').prop('title' , title);
    
    //create the dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog();
}

createDialog(someVariable , someTitle);
```

```html
<head>
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
```